# What is the best program for data mining with connection to sql server?

Tags: sql, data-mining

I'm between Weka and Orange, but I don't know if these can be connected with sql server

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource **are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Also, SQL is rather useless for these tasks. Use SQL to select (and maybe preprocess) the data, dump it into a file, load it into the analysis tools.

Answer (score 1):

Because i think your problem is about connecting to sql server, and this was my problem too, I'll give you the answer:

1. If you want to directly connect to sql server try to use c# with Accord framework http://accord-framework.net/intro.html, this is the most easiest way, because both c# and sql server are from MS corporation
2. there is some solution for weka with JDBC to connect to sql server that require some configuration.
3. you can export sql server result to excel or csv format using sql server explore wizard, then use it in weka or orange: http://bpmdeveloper.com/sql-server-export-wizard-csv/